# Chrome extension OAuth2 SingIn issue - service has beend disabled for this account

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-signin, google-oauth

I have enabled OAuth2 SignIn in my chrome extension, everything is working, users are able to login and use it. But only one user is getting the error while singing-In, the error is `OAuth2 service has been disabled for this account". This extension allowing only to signing for a particular email domain(ie, name@xyz.com),  The one account which is getting the error is the admin of this domain like he can see all other emails. I asked @google chrome extension support, and the guy Yukie suggested to ask it here as they don't have support for this.

Any help would be more than welcome!

Thanks,
Nikhil

Answer (score 0):

After debugging/digging I found that, that user was signed-in in his browser with non @xyz.com email id. And this was the reason of this issue, the error is completely miss-leading here and confusing.

Hope this helps, if not, let me know. We both can check.